# What are the possible reasons that even after successfull execution control doesnt come back to prompt?

Tags: java

I am running a Java Program in command prompt
The normal course is after successfully executing the program it comes back to prompt .. what are the possible reasons it will not come back to prompt after successfully executing the program

why is it not coming back to prompt after execution

[image]

usually it comes back but sometimes it doesn't...

Comment: Can you give more details or source code if you can?

Comment: Probably leaving some non-daemon thread about (for instance the AWT EDT).

Comment: The program parses the pdf . I have closed all the resources. Also the same runs fine and comes back to prompt in most of my friends computers who have same setting as mine. Only difference is in RAM and hard disk capacity mine is slower.. Can it be possible reason?? (I know it sounds weird :) ) And also if so how does it comes back to prompt some times??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a race condition.  Something in your application's shutdown sequence is non-deterministic, and it works or does not work depending on various platform specific (and possibly external) factors.  There is probably no point figuring out what those factors are (or might be), since it won't help you fix the problem.

> Only difference is in RAM hard disk capacity mine is slower.. Can it be possible reason?

These *could* be factors, but they are not the cause of the problem.  So focus on figuring out what makes your application non-deterministic.

As others have said, without more information (and relevant code) we can only guess.

When the application has failed to shut down, get it to give you a thread dump.  Or try shutting it down while it is attached to a debugger.  These may allow you to get some clues as to what is going wrong.

Finally, the brute force solution is simply to have the `main` method (or whatever) call `System.exit(0)` on its way out.  But beware of the possibility of files not being flushed, etc if you do that.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's not finishing. If it's sometimes happening and sometimes not, my instinct is that you have some sort of race condition. Probably one of your cleanup steps is hanging if another action has or hasn't been taken.

Without source code this will be hard to debug.

Comment: If so then why is it coming back to prompt sometimes?? Also same code runs successfully and returns back to prompt in other computers.. Is it memory issue???

Comment: @Asha, because with race conditions it is very hard to predict behavior. It could be that something must happen quick enough in one thread in order to another one to finish execution. On faster computers it happens almost always, on yours it happens less often. This is a kind of bug that isn't very reproducible. Try running it from a debugger and see what threads are still running and where they are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

There could be an active thread still running which is not in "daemon" mode.  For example, if you have a Swing GUI and all of the frames are closed the Event Dispatch thread is still active so the JVM will not exit.